# Real solutions of $x^n+x-c^2=0$

Tags: polynomials

Finding the real positive solution of $x^n+x-c^2;\ 2\lt n\in\mathbb{N},\,c\in\mathbb{R},$ comes from a practical problem I encountered.

> **Question:**
>
> what can be said about exact solutions for specific values of $n$ and/or non-recursive functions $f(\xi,\eta)\mapsto x$ such that yields  $\min\max\limits_{n,c}|f(n,c)^n+f(n,c)-c^2|$.

As the intended use of $f(n,c)$ is to obtain starting points for numeric root finders, that function should not be too complex and yield starting points that significantly reduce the number of iterations needed to achieve a given precision of the solution.

Comment: What are $n$ and $c$ here? And how do you define "best possible estimations"?

Comment: $n\gt 2$ is a positive integer and $c$ is a real value. "Best possible" means the value $x_0$ with the least *provable* upper bound for $|x_0^n+x_0-c^2|$

Comment: The question is still unclear. The least upper bound for $|x^n+x-c^2|$ is obviously $0$, attained when $x$ is the unique nonnegative root of the equation $x^n+x-c^2=0$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis ok, I was unprecise about $x_0$, let me try to make it more precise: which non-recursive function $f(n,c)$ yields $\min\max\limits_{n\gt2} |f(n,c)^n+f(n,c)-c^2|$

Comment: I do not know what you mean by 'non-recursive" in this context.

Comment: I can give you bounds of the form $f(n,c)\le g(a,n,c)$ for $a>A(n,c)$ and $f(n,c)\ge g(a,n,c)$ for $a<A(n,c)$ for all large enough $n$, where $g$ and $A$ are elementary functions, if that is all that you want.

Comment: @IosifPinelis such bounds would be very helpful.

Comment: Could you edit your question, so that there is no need to read the comments to understand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hardly anything interesting can be said here for small $n$. So, let $n$ be large. Let $x=x_{c,n}$ be the unique nonnegative zero of $f(x):=x^n+x-c^2$. We have to distinguish the following three cases.

*Case 1: $c^2<1$.* Then $x<c^2$ and hence
$$c^2-c^{2n}<x_{c,n}<c^2,$$
so that $x_{c,n}=c^2+o(1)$ exponentially fast (as $n\to\infty$).

*Case 2: $c^2=1$.* Let then $z_{a,n}:=1-a\dfrac{\ln n}n$ for real $a>0$. Then for $x=z_{a,n}$ we have
$$f(x)=\Big(1-a\dfrac{\ln n}n\big)^n-a\dfrac{\ln n}n
=n^{-a+o(1)}-a\dfrac{\ln n}n,$$
which is eventually (that is, for all large enough $n$) negative if $a>1$ and eventually positive if $a<1$. Therefore and because $f(x)$ is increasing in $x\ge0$,
$$x_{c,n}=1-(1+o(1))\dfrac{\ln n}n.$$

*Case 3: $c^2>1$.* Let then $w_{a,c,n}:=c^{2/n}e^{-a/n}$ for real $a>0$. Then for $x=w_{a,c,n}$ we have
$$f(x)=c^{2/n}e^{-a/n}-c^2(1-e^{-a})\to1-c^2(1-e^{-a}), $$
which is $<0$ if $a>a_c:=\ln\dfrac{c^2}{c^2-1}$ and  $>0$ if $a<a_c$. Therefore and because $f(x)$ is increasing in $x\ge0$,
$$x_{c,n}=c^{2/n}e^{-(a_c+o(1)/n}=1+\frac{\ln(c^2-1)+o(1)}n$$
(thanks to [Emil Jeřábek](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ipinelis/Published/Untitled-6.nb) for the latter equality).

---

In a previous comment by the OP (now apparently deleted), it was indicated that the desired approximations to the root were intended to be fed to a recursive approximation method as initial approximations. [This Mathematica notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ipinelis/Published/Untitled-6.nb) shows that the approximations given above (with the $o(1)$'s omitted) work well in this role with the Newton method, even for $n$ as small as $5$ or $10$.

Comment: Isn’t $c^{2/n}e^{-(a_c+o(1))/n}=(c^2-1+o(1))^{1/n}$?

Comment: In other words, $x_{c,n}-1\sim\frac1n\log(c^2-1)$

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : Thank you for your comments -- now taken into account.

Comment: @IosifPinelis  very much appreciate the nice and detailed answer you both provided with the contribution of Emil Jerabek .